# Creating an Array of ListenerRegistration in SwiftUI Firestore

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I have a list of groups stored in `self.groups`

I'm looping over these groups, like so

```
for group in groups {

}
```

And then I'm attaching a snapshot listener to each group (which is obviously causing the listeners to leak), like so:

```
for group in groups {
    self.groupListener = ref.addSnapshotListener {...}
}
```

Then, when my user wants to log out, I call `Model.removeAllListeners()`, and this works for all listeners set properly, and *not* inside for-in loops.

However, I've tried to create a `@Published var` which holds an array of `ListenerRegistration`s, like so:

```
@Published var spacesTasksInDayListener: [ListenerRegistration] = []
```

However, when I do, I get the error:

> 'ListenerRegistration' is not convertible to '[ListenerRegistration]'

So my question is, how can I keep a reference to each snapshot listener, if its generated inside a for-in loop?

My current solution is to modify my Firestore Snapshot to return all the documents I want using a proper query function, only assigning one snapshot listener, allowing me to remove it at the end.

However, am I incapable of creating an array of listeners?

Thank you!

P.S. I'm trying to reference all my listeners so that I can call `listenerRef.remove()` when a user logs out

Comment: Can you show the actual line of code where you get the error?

Comment: It's on the `addSnapshotListener` line, but I'm not confused about the error, just wondering if I can make an array of listeners

Comment: Sure you can. Have you tried?

Comment: @jnpdx Yup! I've posted my current solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I've found a solution, however I've also changed a lot of my architecture.

The reason I wanted to add snapshotListeners to an array was so that I can build a way around the `10` limit for `arrayContains` queries, and know when I need to refresh a listener with more things to listen to!

I've created a struct:

```
enum MySnapshotListenerType: String {
    case groups = "groups"
    case members = "members"
}

struct MySnapshotListener: Identifiable {
    let id: String = UUID().uuidString
    
    var listener: ListenerRegistration?
    var type: MySnapshotListenerType?
    var groupID: String?
    var memberID: String?
}
```

And whenever I start a new snapshot listener, I create a reference to it, `.remove any existing, matching snapshot listener type, and append the new one.

```
let newSnapshotReference = path.collection(a_group_id).addSnapshotListener {...}


for snapshotListener in self.snapshotListeners {
    if snapshotListener.type == .groups && snapshotListener.groupID == a_group_id {
        if snapshotListener.listener != nil {
            snapshotListener.listener!.remove()
        }
    }
}

self.snapshotListeners.append(
    MySnapshotListener(
        listener: newSnapshotReference,
        type: .groups,
        groupID: a_group_id
    )
)
```

And now I can safely remove every snapshot listener on user's logout.

If anyone has any suggestions to make this better I'm all ears :)